# How to separate the text file's values using the start and end positions

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

I have a text file:

```
GLKIIM 08052016 08052016 444-22222222 33333 5675555
ABCDEF 87645123 34211016 333-11111111 22222 5123455
```

I am using `CSV.read`  to read the text file.

For each line in the text file, I need to extract the column values by the start and end positions. For that I have arrays:

```
start_pos = [1 8 17 26 30 39 45]
end_pos = [6 15 24 28 37 43 51]
```

which mean in the text file from position `start_pos[0]` to `end_pos[0]`, i.e 1 to 6, we will have the first column's values, `GLKIIM` and `ABCDEF`.

The column names are:

```
column_name = [SOURCE_NAME BATCH_DATE EFFECT_DATE ID ACCOUNT_NO ENTITY ACCOUNT]
```

I need to create a hash as follows:

```
{
  0=>{"SOURCE_NAME"=>"GLKIIM", "BATCH_DATE"=>"08052016", "EFFECT_DATE"=>"08052016", "ID"=>"444", "ACCOUNT_NO"=>"22222222", "ENTITY"=>"33333", "ACCOUNT"=>"5675555"},
  1=>{"SOURCE_NAME"=>"ABCDEF", "BATCH_DATE"=>"87645123", "EFFECT_DATE"=>"34211016", "ID"=>"333", "ACCOUNT_NO"=>"11111111", "ENTITY"=>"22222", "ACCOUNT"=>"5123455"}
}
```

I cannot use space () as a delimiter to segregate the columns values, I need to use the start and end positions.

Comment: Using `CSV.read` is somewhat pointless if you don't have a fixed delimiter. However, what have you tried so far to extract the columns? The task doesn't look that hard.

Comment: @Stefan what i know is that if i read the text file line by line as follows:

file = File.open('data_file.TXT', "r")
file.each_line do |line|
puts line[start_pos[0]..end_pos[0]]
end

it will give me the first column value

Comment: `line[start_pos[1]..end_pos[1]]` will give you the second and so on. What problem are you facing?

Comment: Are there values with spaces? Otherwise just split on space.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. If it is I'd suggest searching [meta] for "homework" and read the questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below code:

```
file = File.open('abc.TXT', "r")
i = 0
file.each_line do |line|
    temp = {}
    for itrator in 0..column_name.length-1
          temp[column_name[itrator]] = line[start_pos[itrator]-1..end_pos[itrator]-1]
        end
        data_hash[i] = temp
        i+=1
      end
puts data_hash
```

Assuming that file name containing the following data is `abc.txt`:

```
GLKIIM 08052016 08052016 444-22222222 33333 5675555
ABCDEF 87645123 34211016 333-11111111 22222 5123455
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not read the file as a Comma-Separated-Values (CSV) file, if it isn't one.
Using "speaking code" you could use `File.readlines` instead:

```
#!/bin/env ruby

result = ARGF.readlines.map do |line|                                     
  [line[0..5], line[7..14], line[16..23], line[24..36]]                   
end                                                                       

puts result.inspect
# => [["GLKIIM", "08052016", "08052016", " 444-22222222"], ["ABCDEF", "87645123", "34211016", " 333-11111111"]]
```

If you save this script you can run it as:

```
readliner.rb MYFILE.TXT MYFILE2.TXT MYFILE3.TXT
```

or pipe into it:

```
cat myfile | readliner.rb
```

Alternatively use

```
File.readlines("MYFILE.TXT")
```

instead of `ARGF.readlines` in the script.
The use of `readlines` can bring problems with it, as it reads the whole file into memory to yield an array of lines. See the comments for a small discussion on that topic.

Let's code-golf a bit, while staying somewhat readable and removing `readlines`:

```
#!/bin/env ruby

COLS = { "SOURCE_NAME" => 0..5,
         "BATCH_DATE"  => 7..14,
         "EFFECT_DATE" => 16..23 }

result = ARGF.each_with_index.map do |line, idx|
  [idx, COLS.map{|name,range| [name, line[range]] }.to_h ]
end.to_h

puts result.inspect
# => {0=>{"SOURCE_NAME"=>"GLKIIM", "BATCH_DATE"=>"08052016", "EFFECT_DATE"=>"08052016"}, 1=>{"SOURCE_NAME"=>"ABCDEF", "BATCH_DATE"=>"87645123", "EFFECT_DATE"=>"34211016"}}
```

Comment: Be careful using `readlines`. It isn't scalable and can actually break your code if the file being read is too big. It also can slow your code. Use `foreach` instead.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for your edits and comment. I dont have the time to check the code of `each_line` or simply `each_with_index` (where does `foreach` come from btw?), probably one of these is friendlier then readlines (which is not lazy iiuc). And the problem will still be there if the line itself is huge, isnt it?

Comment: `foreach` comes from the IO class, but we usually access it via `File`. It's much more likely to run into a huge file that will cause problems than a single line that was cause the same problem. As for having time, when answering it's important to put in the time. It's not a race.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for clarification. I removed `readlines` from the final example and referenced the comments-section. My C skills are somewhat rusty and I will not dig into the implementations of `each_with_index`, `each_line` or `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

```
input = 'GLKIIM 08052016 08052016 444-22222222 33333 5675555
ABCDEF 87645123 34211016 333-11111111 22222 5123455'
start_pos = %w|1 8 17 26 30 39 45|.map &:to_i
end_pos   = %w|6 15 24 28 37 43 51|.map &:to_i

input.split($/).map do |line|
  start_pos.zip(end_pos).map { |s, e| line[s-1..e-1] }
end
#⇒  [["GLKIIM", "08052016", "08052016", "444", "22222222", "33333", "5675555"],
#    ["ABCDEF", "87645123", "34211016", "333", "11111111", "22222", "5123455"]]
```

Comment: Why don't we have, say, `%x|1 817 26 30 39 45| #=> [1,817,26,30,39,45]`?  It's not for want of available letters. Maybe it's because there's no reduction in the time it takes to type `[1,817,26,30,39,45]`. :-)

Comment: Because `%x` is the same as using backticks. Why isn't there a `%`-based array for numeric arrays, and one for floats? Good question. Perhaps bounce it off the developers. The idea for `%w|a b|` being preferred to `["a", "b"]` is it reduces visual noise and makes it easier to quickly add/modify elements, and helps reduce the chance of missing a starting or ending quote and causing a bug.

Comment: @theTinMan Frankly, I used this [a bit weird] `map &:to_i` because OP had [not valid] `start_pos = [1 8 17 26 30 39 45]` declaration and I type way faster than I put commas in between values in a list separated by spaces.